# Difference between class and instance methods

Tags: python

I was reading [PEP 8](https://pep8.org/) ([style guide](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/)), and I noticed that it suggested to use *self* as the first argument in an instance method, but *cls* as the first argument in a class method.

I've used and written a few classes, but I've never encountered a class method (well, a method which passes *cls* as a parameter). What are some examples?

Comment: IMHO, this isn't a duplicate. While similar in nature, this post is focused on a pythonic solution while the other uses references towards java and focuses on the theory. a) not everyone knows java and b) sometimes application by example is better than a terse theoretical explanation. I personally don't feel the "linked answer" is the answer. The posted answer here is. And while working in tandem, might create a better understanding, lacks a clarified direction and creates further confusion.

Answer (score 141, accepted):

### Instance methods

When creating an instance method, the first parameter is always `self`.
You can name it anything you want, but the meaning will always be the same, and you should use `self` since it's the naming convention.
`self` is (usually) passed hiddenly when calling an instance method; it represents the instance calling the method.

Here's an example of a class called `Inst` that has an instance method called `introduce()`:

```
class Inst:

    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name

    def introduce(self):
        print("Hello, I am %s, and my name is " %(self, self.name))
```

Now to call this method, we first need to create an instance of our class.
Once we have an instance, we can call `introduce()` on it, and the instance will automatically be passed as `self`:

```
myinst = Inst("Test Instance")
otherinst = Inst("An other instance")
myinst.introduce()
# outputs: Hello, I am <Inst object at x>, and my name is Test Instance
otherinst.introduce()
# outputs: Hello, I am <Inst object at y>, and my name is An other instance
```

As you see, we're not passing the parameter `self`. It gets hiddenly passed with the period operator. We're calling `Inst` class's instance method `introduce`, with the parameter of `myinst` or `otherinst`.
This means that we can call `Inst.introduce(myinst)` and get the exact same result.

---

### Class methods

The idea of a class method is very similar to an instance method, only difference being that instead of passing the instance hiddenly as a first parameter, we're now passing the class itself as a first parameter.

```
class Cls:

    @classmethod
    def introduce(cls):
        print("Hello, I am %s!" %cls)
```

Since we're passing only a class to the method, no instance is involved.

This means that we don't need an instance at all, and we call the class method as if it was a static function:

```
 Cls.introduce() # same as Cls.introduce(Cls)
 # outputs: Hello, I am <class 'Cls'>
```

Notice that again `Cls` is passed hiddenly, so we could also say `Cls.introduce(Inst)` and get output `"Hello, I am <class 'Inst'>`.

This is particularly useful when we're inheriting a class from `Cls`:

```
class SubCls(Cls):
    pass

SubCls.introduce()
# outputs: Hello, I am <class 'SubCls'>
```

Answer (score 3):

An instance method, simply put, is a function defined inside of a class. It varies with the different instances of the class.
Example:

```
class Dog:
    def __init__(self, sound):
        self.sound = sound
    def bark(self):
        return f"The dog makes the sound: {self.sound}"
```

Whereas a class method is a method which, unlike the bark() method, is applied to all instances of the class.