# Object with __init__ in python

Tags: python

I have written some python code:

```
class key(object):
    def __init__(self,name):
        object.__init__(self,age)
        this.name = name
        this.age = age

    def somefunction(self):
        print "yay the name is %d" % self.name

baby = key('radan',20)
baby.somefunction()
```

When I create an instance of `key` with `baby = key('radan',20)`, I got a TypeError. I don't know why I am getting this error. Is it because of `object.__init__(self,age)`?

If yes, please help me in explaining why we use `object.__init__(self,age)` and what the purpose of that is and help me solve this code.

Comment: `%d` in string formatting expects a number, but `self.name` is a string... you probably want to use `%s` instead.

Comment: i have tried it with %s too ..But i get the same error

Comment: Oh, missed that. It makes no sense here to call `object.__init__` at all, just remove that line.

Comment: @user3517846 There you go, see my answer- happy to help.

Comment: can you tell me the use of object.__init__(self, name, age)...in which situation we use it ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code contains several errors:

```
class key(object):
    def __init__(self, name, age): # where's your age?
        self.name = name  # no need to call object.__init__
        self.age = age    # there is no such thing called "this", use self

    def somefunction(self):
        print "yay the name is %s" % self.name  # use %s as the comment says

baby = key('radan', 20)
baby.somefunction()
```

output:

```
>>> baby = key('radan', 20)
>>> baby.somefunction()
yay the name is radan
```

Comment: can you tell me the use of object.__init__(self, name, age)...in which situation we use it ?

Comment: @user3517846 If your class is directly inherited from `object`, then you'll never need to call `object.__init__()`

Comment: can you give me a link or something or can you please explain more its use ..in some code i have seen using object.__init__(self) ..i didnt understand its usage ..Please help me

Comment: @user3517846 In what code have you seen `object.__init__(self)`?

Comment: i dunno am not so clear but i have seen objec.__init__(self,name) like that ...Can you please tell me why its using like that

Comment: I have accepted your answer ..please tell me the correct situation to use object.__init__(self,name)

Comment: @user3517846 ok give me some time to search cause for me I've never used or seen code written like that. If I find some useful information I'll tell you.

Comment: @user3517846 I'll comment here

Comment: will be waiting for your comment

Comment: @user3517846 After searching for a while, my answer is still "NO, there is no such usage". I think what you saw is that people are using the  word `object` to refer to general class instances, for instance you'll find it in the official doc:  https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__init__, but that doesn't mean to write `object.__init__(self...)`, it means object is an instance whatever type it is. my email is laike9m@gmail.com in case you want to know more.

Comment: I understood and can you tell me why we use  the word object with the classname ?

Comment: @user3517846 Because `__init__` is instance method not clas method, please refer to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17134653/difference-between-class-and-instance-methods.

Answer (score 1):

Some pointers:

```
class Key(object): # in Python, classes are usually named with a starting capital

    def __init__(self, name, age): # name all your arguments beside self

        self.name = name # use self.name, not this.name
        self.age = age

    def somefunction(self):

        print "yay the name is %s" % self.name

baby = Key('radan',20)
baby.somefunction()
# output: yay the name is radan
```

Actually, you can can name the `self` instance parameter whatever you like in Python (even `this`), but it makes the code harder to read for other people, so just use `self`.

You don't have to use `object.__init__(self, name, age)` here. If you remove that line and implement the changes above, your code will work just fine.

Comment: can you tell me the use of object.__init__(self, name, age)...in which situation we use it

Comment: Maybe [this explanation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/625083/python-init-and-self-what-do-they-do) will be of help to you.

Comment: so its not necessary to use object.__init__(self, name, age) ..right ?

Comment: No, that's not necessary. I don't understand why you would want to initialize `object` in the first place. Class `Key` inherits from `object` (all classes do), but there is no need to initialize `object`. `object` is what classes come from, it is the most base type of thing. When a class inherits from `object` it means it just inherits the standard special methods like `__init__`, `__doc__`, `__str__`, etc. I have yet to encounter an example where `object` is initialized the way you say, so please post the original code.

Answer (score 0):

When you do `baby = key('radar', 20)` you are actually passing **three** arguments: the instance, the `name` and the `age`. However your initialiser is defined to take exactly two arguments so you get a `TypeError`.

`self` is the argument implicitly passed when referring to an instance of an object.

For your `__init__` function, I would just do:

```
def __init__(self, name, age):
    self.name = name
    self.age = age
```

So we can assign the arguments passed as attributes to the current instance, conventionally called `self`.

It makes no sense here to call `object.__init__` at all, just remove that line.

---

Apart from that, everything works fine (except use `%s` instead of `%d`).

Testing:

```
>>> baby = key('radan', 20)
>>> baby.somefunction()
yay the name is radan
```

Comment: can you tell me the use of object.__init__(self, name, age)...in which situation we use it ?