# Understanding ObjC bad message examples?

Tags: objective-c, class, instance, method-call

I'm currently reading **The Big Nerd Ranch Guide** on Objective C programming and I'm having trouble understanding a section in **Chapter 13, Objects** which is providing bad examples of Messages:

```
NSDate *now = [NSDate date];
double seconds = [now timeIntervalSince1970];
```

This is firstly a **correct example** of using messages in Objc. The first line creates a pointer to an NSDate object using the variable `now` and the NSDate type declaration. It is now an instance of NSDate. It was explained to me that if you are to print `now`, it will display the output of the NSDate date method. This is where things start to get a little weird for me. It seems odd that you would have a variable pointing both to an instance, and a function output if printed. But that's okay. Moving on.

The second line creates a variable called `seconds`, which is of type "double" and is going to obtain a value that the timeIntervalSince1970 method of NSDate instance `now` outputs.

Here is where the author introduces examples of **bad messages**:

```
double testSeconds = [NSDate timeIntervalSince1970];
NSDate *testNow = [now date];
```

He explains the errors as follows:

**First Line**:

> "The Error is clear, the receiver in this message send is the NSDate
>   class, so the selector should be the name of an NSDate class method.
>   This selector is not."

Ok. This makes sense. An invalid method. Next. .

**Second Line:**

> "This error is less clear: It is telling you that NSDate has no
>   instance method whose name matches the date selector."

Wait, what? Isn't `now` a pointer to an instance of NSDate? Shouldn't you be able to call the date method from an instance of NSDate? I don't get it.

The book does not explain any more than what I've quoted above, so I'm sure it's something stupid and basic I'm not getting. I hope this isn't too specific or unhelpful to others. I'll delete the submission if asked. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The variable `now` points to an **instance** of `NSDate`. The method `date` is not defined on instances of `NSDate` but on the class itself. Hence `date` is a **class method** and not an **instance method**. Unlike other programming languages Objective-C does not inherit class methods to their class instances.

Vice versa instance methods cannot be called on classes. This said `timeIntervalSince1970` cannot be called on the class `NSDate` as this method is an **instance method**. This is due to the circumstances that instances usually manage an **instance state**. Instance methods do operate on this instance state, namely reading and modifying their **instance variables**. Back to your example: The instance method `timeIntervalSince1970` calculates the difference between 01/01/1970 and a concrete, instantiated date. So if you would be able to call `timeIntervalSince1970` on class level there's no chance to calculate a difference of dates as the class `NSDate` doesn't carry any date information (the instance state!) such as the day, month, year and the time.

To sum up: Instance methods cannot be called on classes. This isn't supported by any programing language I am aware of. Calling class methods on instances is however supported by some programing language although there's typically no need for doing so and sometimes it even lowers code readability. However Objective-C doesn't support those calls neither.

Comment: So instances of NSDate, don't "inherit" NSDate class methods? And instance methods are only available to instances of objects? This seems so confusing. Coming from python where a class instance inherited all class methods. And where instance methods are unheard of. I think I'll have to read the chapter again. Thanks. . .

Comment: Forgot to tag in Original reply

Comment: @Owatch No, `NSDate` does not inherit its class methods to its instances. And yes, instance methods are only available to instances of classes. Please be aware of the correct wording: _Instance of class_ = _object_. Please see also my updated answer regarding your questions.

Comment: @Owatch Are you sure that Python doesn't have instance methods? Also Python (unfortunately) isn't a language I've used so far, I found that instance methods do exist: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17134653/difference-between-class-and-instance-methods

Comment: Well, when the linked example discusses instance methods, it's not that separate methods exist for instances, but more that certain methods will not work unless an instance exists. The use of 'self' in Python is useful in instances because you can assign local variables to individual instances. If the method of an object sets a variable NAME to self.NAME. It makes self.NAME accessible across all methods of the object. Rather than localized to that method. It seems I wasn't thinking of instance methods the same way. Instance methods only work when an instance exists.

Comment: Not somehow appear when an instance is created as I was incorrectly interpreting it before, even if that's silly.

Comment: @Owatch: Methods on classes and methods on an instance are different in Python. If you try to call a method on an instance that is actually defined on the class, you get a method with one less parameter (a bound method, where the first parameter is bound to the instance), which is different than if you have a method defined on the instance directly, in which case there is no argument for the instance.