# Why does this error say I'm giving the function two arguments?

Tags: python

I define a graph class which has a function for taking a node name and adding the name and node to a dictionary.When I run the program, I receive the error at the bottom. Why does it think I am giving it two arguments?

```
class Graph:

    def __init__(self):
        self.node_list = {}
        self.number = 0

    def node(node_name):
        if node_name in self.node_list.keys:
            return node_list[node_name]
        else:
            node_list[node_name] = Node()
    ...

def PrefixTrieConstruction(patterns):
    trie = Graph()
    trie.node('root')

for pattern in patterns:
    currentNode = trie.node('root')
    for symbol in pattern:
        for daughter in currentNode.daughters:
            if daughter.label == symbol:
                currentNode = daughter
                break
        else:
            node_name = Trie.name_node()
            Trie.node(node_name)
            Trie.edge(currentNode, node_name, symbol)
            currentNode = node_name
return Trie



Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "PythonProject2.3.py", line 168, in <module>
    main()
  File "PythonProject2.3.py", line 163, in main
    TrieMatching(text, PrefixTrieConstruction(patterns))
  File "PythonProject2.3.py", line 68, in PrefixTrieConstruction
    trie.node('root')
TypeError: node() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given
```

Answer (score 4):

You are missing `self`:

```
def node(self,node_name):
```

`self` refers to the instance you are calling the method on so you are already passing the instance so passing `'root'` will obviously give you the error you see.

`trie.node('root')` is basically doing `Graph.node(trie,"root")` so you are passing two args to a method that takes one, the `node_name` in your method is being interpreted as the instance so `'root'` is an extra argument, unless you are using static or class  methods the first arg to your methods should always be `self`, it can be any name but almost every python programmer by convention uses `self` to refer to the instance.

[difference-between-class-and-instance-methods](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17134653/difference-between-class-and-instance-methods)

[what-is-the-difference-between-staticmethod-and-classmethod-in-python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/136097/what-is-the-difference-between-staticmethod-and-classmethod-in-python)

[what-is-the-purpose-of-self-in-python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2709821/what-is-the-purpose-of-self-in-python)

Comment: Ok, so all class methods have to have 'self', but __init__ does not?

Comment: @jukhamil, it depends, static method don't need self but at the basic level you should always be using self and init does also need self.

Comment: I added a couple of links relating to the different types of meths, it is a broad subject which comments could not cover.

Answer (score 2):

That's an easy one ! 
The function `node` takes only one parameter, but is located in a class. Given the implicit class instance and your parameter, that's 2 arguments. To fix it, you can edit the function to

```
     def node(self,node_name):
```

Answer (score 1):

In python, the first argument to a method is always the object on which the method is called. This variable is called `self` by convention, but there's no rule saying this must be the case. So when you write:

```
def node(node_name):
```

`node_name` is interpreted as the "self" variable and the expected usage of the function is:

```
trie.node() #within this call, trie is bound to node_name
```

So when you write:

```
trie.node('root')
```

`trie` is bound to `node_name` and `'root'` is an extra argument, causing an error.

To get your intended behavior, simply declare the `self` variable:

```
def node(self, node_name):
```