# TypeError: takes exactly 1 argument (0 given) - Scrapy

Tags: python, scrapy

I'm working with scrapy. I want to generate a unique user agent for each request. I have the following:

```
class ContactSpider(Spider):
    name = "contact"

    def getAgent(self):
        f = open('useragentstrings.txt')
        agents = f.readlines()
        return random.choice(agents).strip()

    headers = {          
        'user-agent': getAgent(),
        'content-type': "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
        'cache-control': "no-cache"
    }

    def parse(self, response):
        open_in_browser(response)
```

getAgent generates an agent from a list of the form:

```
"Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/52.0.2743.116 Safari/537.36"
```

However when I run this I get:

```
  File "..spiders\contact_spider.py, line 35, in <module>
    class ContactSpider(Spider):
  File "..spiders\contact_spider.py", line 54, in ContactSpider
    'user-agent': getAgent(),
TypeError: getAgent() takes exactly 1 argument (0 given)
```

Comment: Try `'user-agent': self.getAgent()`

Comment: I tried that earlier but it gives me:     'user-agent': self.getAgent(),
NameError: name 'self' is not defined

Comment: `getAgent(None)` or use `def getAgent()`, or move that def outside class without self

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`getAgent()` is an *instance method* and expects to see the `ContactSpider` instance as an argument. But, the problem is, you don't need this function to be a member of your spider class - move it to a separate "helpers"/"utils"/"libs" module and import:

```
from helpers import getAgent

class ContactSpider(Spider):
    name = "contact"

    headers = {          
        'user-agent': getAgent(),
        'content-type': "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
        'cache-control': "no-cache"
    }

    def parse(self, response):
        open_in_browser(response)
```

See also: [Difference between Class and Instance methods](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17134653/difference-between-class-and-instance-methods).

---

Or, as an alternative approach, there is a [`scrapy-fake-user-agent`](https://github.com/alecxe/scrapy-fake-useragent) Scrapy middleware that would rotate user agents seamlessly and randomly. User Agent strings are supplied by the [`fake-useragent` module](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/fake-useragent).

Comment: Thank you, that's very helpful. I read though some references on class and instance methods in python, but I'm still confused because when I define def getAgent(self) am I not passing an instance of ContactSpider to it?

Comment: @user61629 no problem, when you define `getAgent` as `def getAgent(self)` you expect `getAgent` to be called on an instance of your `ContactSpider` class, but you are calling it via just `getAgent()`. In any case, if you don't reference or don't need the class instance inside the method - this is an indication that you either can make a method static, or should move the function from out the class..sorry, I am terrible at explaining things clearly :)

Comment: Its definitely true that getAgent() stands alone and does not require the class, In fact I had it as a standalone function before moving it into the class. Thanks,  I will keep reading about this!

Comment: Would you mind looking at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39430264/how-to-add-a-third-party-scrapy-middleware ?