# How to add a third party Scrapy middleware

Tags: python, scrapy

[image]

I'm working with scrapy 1.1 . I want to add [`scrapy-fake-user-agent`](https://github.com/alecxe/scrapy-fake-useragent) Scrapy middleware that would rotate user agents seamlessly and randomly. User Agent strings are supplied by the [`fake-useragent` module](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/fake-useragent).

following the directions from the site, I have:

```
DOWNLOADER_MIDDLEWARES = {
    'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.useragent.UserAgentMiddleware': None,
    'scrapy_fake_useragent.middleware.RandomUserAgentMiddleware': 400,
}
```

However when I run it I get:

```
ImportError: No module named scrapy_fake_useragent.middleware
```

What am I doing wrong?

edit: I opened a python shell in the virtualenv:

```
In[4]: import scrapy.downloadermiddlewares as x
In[5]: x.useragent.UserAgentMiddleware
Out[5]: scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.useragent.UserAgentMiddleware

In[7]: import scrapy_fake_useragent as x
In[8]: dir(x)
Out[8]: ['__builtins__', '__doc__', '__file__', '__name__', '__package__', '__path__']
```

So 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.useragent.UserAgentMiddleware 'seems to be available but not 'scrapy_fake_useragent.middleware.RandomUserAgentMiddleware' ?

Comment: Is it properly installed? What happens if you try something like `python -c "import scrapy_fake_useragent.middleware"` in the same environment?

Comment: The project is missing a `pip install scrapy-fake-useragent` instruction beforehand.

Comment: Ran that but I'm getting the same error - please see screenshot

Comment: @user61629 have you executed `pip install scrapy-fake-useragent` in the same Python environment you run your scrapy project in?

Comment: Yes - I'm working in win7 with pycharm - the screenshot is from pycharm

Comment: please see edit

Comment: A quick update - it turned out that in scrapy app in pycharm was using a different virtualenv than in the python shell.  I used import sys print(sys.executable) in both the script and in the shell and compared the result to figure this out. I've fixed this and the original error has been resolved.

Answer (score 0):

I too had the same problem. Later I noticed that I am not inside the virutalenv. Those packages were installed in virutalenv. When moved into virtualenv, it is fine.