# How to make def statement return an object within a self(...)

Tags: python, class, self

```
class Items():
    def Bucket(self):
        self.cost(5)

print(Items.Bucket()) # I want this to return the cost of the item
```

I want this to print the cost of the item listed. In this case a bucket which i want it to return 5. Right now it returns...

```
TypeError: Bucket() missing 1 required positional argument: 'self'
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: `Items().Bucket())`. You have to instantiate your `Items` first. Or redefine `Bucket` to `def Bucket():`.

Comment: Note: your bucket won't return anything, since there's no `return` statement.

Comment: Thank you that gave me an idea.

Comment: Do this - class Items():
                    def Bucket():
                          cost = int(5)
                          return cost                                                                                              -             print(Items.Bucket())

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason why you are getting this error is because your `Bucket` method is defined as an *instance* method, and you are trying to call it as a *class* method.

I suggest you read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17134653/difference-between-class-and-instance-methods) here about the difference between class methods and instance methods. Which will also explain how *self* plays a role here.

To make an instance of `Items`, you need to *call* it:

```
items_obj = Items()
```

Now, you have an instance of the `Items` class, and can now properly call your method `Bucket`:

```
items_obj.Bucket()
```

It seems like you are already calling a method inside your `Bucket` method called `cost`. So, assuming that this method simply returns the cost then just *return* calling `self.cost(5)` in your `Bucket` method:

```
def Bucket(self):
    return self.cost(5)
```

So, you should have as a final solution:

```
class Items:
    def Bucket(self):
        return self.cost(5)

items_obj = Items()
print(items_obj.Bucket())
```

Note: You don't need to have `()` when defining your class. Assuming you are using Python 3, you can just define your class as: `class Items:` as indicated above.

Also, it would be good to conform to good style practice in your code, by taking a look at the style-guide here: https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/

Comment: Thank you, this really helps

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
class Items():
    def __init__(self,cost):
        self.cost = cost
    def bucket(self):
        return self.cost

items = Items(5)
print(items.bucket())
```