# geopy TypeError : geocode() missing 1 required positional argument: 'query'

Tags: python, google-maps, python-3.x, geopy

I am sorry if this is a too basic question however I am unable to understand a simple error that geopy is throwing at me.

```
In [78]: import geopy

In [79]: geopy.geocoders.Nominatim.geocode("Mumbai")
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-79-2465009b9d72> in <module>()
----> 1 geopy.geocoders.Nominatim.geocode("Mumbai")

TypeError: geocode() missing 1 required positional argument: 'query'
```

However, the following works and I am not getting how these two approaches are different:

```
In [83]: from geopy.geocoders import Nominatim

In [84]: geolocator = Nominatim()

In [85]: geolocator.geocode("Mumbai")
Out[85]: Location(Mumbai, Greater Bombay, Maharashtra, India, (18.9321862, 72.8308337, 0.0))
```

As far as I can see, both seem to be equivalent. What am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that in the first case, you don't create an instance of the `Nominatum` class and try to call a [`geocode()` instance method](https://github.com/geopy/geopy/blob/master/geopy/geocoders/osm.py#L88) with a single argument. Since there is no instance, `Mumbai` is used as the `self` positional argument value leaving the required `query` argument not-specified - hence the error.

The both options would be equivalent if `geocode()` would be a "class method" instead of being an "instance method" ([reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17134653/difference-between-class-and-instance-methods)).