# If statement with callable function in python

Tags: python, if-statement

In C++     if(function())
returns false or true

but how is done in python?
I ve tried:

```
if function() == True:
```

Help!

Why is self needed?

```
def func(self,word):
   if word == 'Hello':
      return True 
word = 'Hello'
if func(word):
   print(word)
```

why is asking to put self?? if func(self,word)?

Comment: Do you not have an interpreter? If is a control-flow statement. It doesn't return anything. If the value of `function` in `if function():` is is truthy, then the block executes. `if function() == True` will only execute if the value returned by the function == True.

Comment: That "_in C++ if(function()) returns false or true_" is entirely false.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following code works just fine:

```
def return_true():
    return True

if return_true():
   print("It's true!")

if return_true() == True:
   print("It's also true!")
```

Just make sure you're function is correctly returning `True`, maybe modify it so the return is just `return True` to check it's the `if` statement and not the function itself.

Comment: def func(self, word):
    return True

Comment: Yes, that function should work as intended (i.e. return true). Also you can use tildes (\`) to do code in comments: `def func(self,word): return True`. Remember to indent correctly as in Python, whitespace is important (the return should be on another line).

Comment: I edited the post with an example,    seems to work what you provided, but why it wants me to put the "self" word, and not just if func(arg):, but instead wants if func(self, arg)?

Comment: It doesn't `self` is only required for `instance` methods in a `class`. This is why my example didn't use `self`.  `def func(word): return True` is perfectly acceptable. If you are writing a `class`, then `self` is required. In `C++` terms `self` simply defines a function that is not static in a class (i.e. works on a single instance).

Comment: Could take a look again at the post and just give me a quick explanation of why "self" is needed when calling a function in an IF statement ?

Comment: I just did in my comment, for a better explanation of `self` see the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17134653/difference-between-class-and-instance-methods). It has nothing to do with the if statement.

Comment: OK I get it, thanks a lot...      Yes the function is in a class and requires the self like if func(self, arg):       but without any class, it works like you stated.

Comment: @Darkstarone technically `self` is just a naming convention used for the instance method of a class. You _can_ name it something other than `self` and the code works the same.

Comment: @Vincenzzzochi I know, it says that in the linked question, I just didn't want to overcomplicate things!