# Python ERROR: TypeError: ... missing 1 required positional argument:

Tags: python, class

```
class Estudante:
    def __init__(self,nome,numero_estudante):
        self.nome=nome
        self.numero_estudante=numero_estudante
        self.cadeiras = []

    def enrol (self, curso_decorrer):
        self.cadeiras.append(curso_decorrer)
        curso_decorrer.add_estudante(self)

class Departamento:
    def __init__(self,nome, codigo_departamento, local):
        self.nome=nome
        self.codigo_departamento = codigo_departamento
        self.local= local
        self.cursos = []

    def add_curso(self,descricao,codigo_curso, creditos,departamento):
        self.cursos[codigo_curso] = Curso(self,descricao,codigo_curso, creditos,departamento)
        return self.cursos[codigo_curso]

class Curso:
    def __init__(self,descricao,codigo_curso, creditos,departamento):
        self.descricao = descricao
        self.codigo_curso= codigo_curso
        self.creditos=creditos
        self.departamento=departamento
        self.departamento.add_curso(self)
        self.decorridos =[]

    def adicionar_ano(self,ano):
        self.decorridos.append(Cursodecorrer(self,ano))
        return self.decorridos[-1]

class Cursodecorrer:
    def __init__(self,curso,ano):
        self.curso = curso
        self.ano = ano
        self.estudantes =[]

    def adicionar_estudante(self,estudante):
        self.estudantes.append(estudante)

Engenharia=Departamento("Departamento de Engenharia","001","Azurém")
Matemática=Departamento("Departamento de Matemática","002","Braga")
MIEBIOM=Departamento.add_curso("Engenharia Biomédica",'001-1',"55","Engenharia")
MIEBIOL=Departamento.add_curso("Engenharia Biológica",'001-2',"55","Engenharia")
MAT=Departamento.add_curso("Matemática",'002-1',"30")
MIEBIOM_2017=Curso.adicionar_ano("2017")
A74000=Estudante("Pedro Miguel","74000")
```

> Code error:  MIEBIOM=Departamento.add_curso("Engenharia
>   Biomédica",'001-1',"55","Engenharia")**

```
TypeError: add_curso() missing 1 required positional argument: 'departamento'
```

I tried everything, anyone knows what's wrong?

Comment: `MAT=Departamento.add_curso("Matemática",'002-1',"30")` seems like it's missing an argument.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [TypeError: Missing 1 required positional argument: 'self'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17534345/typeerror-missing-1-required-positional-argument-self)

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please take the time to read [ask] and the links it contains.

Comment: Read the error message that you're getting. Tell me what it says.

Comment: `add_curso` is being called as a class method, not an instance method.

Comment: TypeError: add_curso() missing 1 required positional argument: 'departamento'

Answer (score 2):

Calling a method directly on a class you should only do with class methods. You should first create an instance of Departamento on which you can call the instance method add_curso.

Here's an example of such a code where you first create a Departamento and then add a curso to it, which I guess is what you want to do:

```
dep = Departamento("name", "codigo dep", "local")
dep.add_curso("Engenharia Biomédica",'001-1',"55","Engenharia")
```

You can see it is an instance method because the first argument in the method definition is self (this is a convention).

More about class methods vs instance methods: [Difference between Class and Instance methods](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17134653/difference-between-class-and-instance-methods)

Comment: But I already did that didn't I?  
With:

`Engenharia=Departamento("Departamento de Engenharia","001","Azurém")`

`MIEBIOM=Departamento.add_curso("Engenharia Biomédica",'001-1',"55","Engenharia")`

Comment: Yes, but you have to use the variable name "Engenharia" and not the class name "Departamento" to call the method:

    `Engenharia=Departamento("Departamento de Engenharia","001","Azurém")
    MIEBIOM=Engenharia.add_curso("Engenharia Biomédica",'001-1',"55","Engenharia")`

Answer (score 1):

Your `add_curso` function requires 5 values

```
def add_curso(self,descricao,codigo_curso, creditos,departamento):
```

But you are passing only 4 values when you are calling it in this line:

```
MIEBIOM=Departamento.add_curso("Engenharia Biomédica",'001-1',"55","Engenharia")
```

So Python interprets it like this:

```
self = "Engenharia Biomedica"
descricao = "001-1"
codigo_curso = "55"
creditos = "Engenharia"
departamento = !!Missing Value!!
```

Hope this helps.