# passing variables back to a class in python

Tags: python, class, global

I'm new, please bear with me. Below is my code:

```
class Player():
    name = "UnknownName"
    stren = 10
    dex = 10
    con = 10
    intel = 10
    wis = 10
    cha = 10

    def randAssign(self):
        global stren, dex, con, intel, wis, cha
        stat_List = [stren, dex, con, intel, wis, cha]

        for stat in stat_List:
             r_1 = random.randint(1,6)
             r_2 = random.randint(1,6)
             r_3 = random.randint(1,6)
             r_4 = random.randint(1,6)

             stat_Val = r_1 + r_2 + r_3 + r_4 - min(r_1, r_2, r_3, r_4)
             stat = stat_Val
```

randAssign is a method in Player()
I'm trying to set a player's stats randomly, and need to rewrite the class variables at the time randAssign() is activated.
For one reason or another, the use of global passes the following error:

```
NameError: name 'stren' is not defined.
```

Using Nonlocal yields this error:

```
SyntaxError: no binding for nonlocal 'stren' found
```

Without either global or nonlocal, it just doesn't rewrite `Player()'s` variables.
I've done a dozen iterations of this, from the outright wrong to the "I thought this would work but it doesn't", and need help.

Comment: why are you trying to use global vars to modify the values inside your class ? To rewrite player variable, you need to modify `self.stren` and assign your new value.

Comment: This is an [XY-Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Answer (score 3):

Defining your variables inside your class like this will make all instances of your class share these variables, which can lead to funky situations (especially for mutable objects). (refer to [Python documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html#class-and-instance-variables)) What you most likely want to do is to use this:

```
class Player:

    def __init__(self):
        self.stren = 10
        self.xcx = 10
        etc.

    def randAssign(self):
        self.stren = randint(1,10)
        ...
```

Comment: Sharing the default values is not so bad (as long as they are immutable objects like integers).

Comment: @Graipher it's not bad,it can be useful, but from I try to understand from his problem, this is not the wanted behaviour, he want to have different players with different stats ?

Comment: Since they are immutable, they will be overwritten only for the instance, not all instances.

Comment: You only have to be careful if you are doing e.g. `player.some_list.append(something)`. That of course modifies the object shared by all instances, instead of modifying only that instance.

Comment: The mutability or immutability is irrelevant to whether they are shared between all instances. They are always shared by instances. Also, @Graipher, mutable and immutable objects will be overwritten just the same.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga True if you are re-assigning them. I just wanted to warn against doing `player.some_list.append(something)`, with `some_list` being a class attribute, and expecting only the instance `player` to be modified.

Comment: @Graipher Unless they deepcopy the class variable to an instance variable, but as I pointed out to juanpa already, OP's issue was on scoping; we've all done more than asked.

Answer (score 1):

Since you already pass the `self` argument in  your function definition, you should refer to these variables in the appropriate namespace:

```
self.stren = ...
```

instead of

```
globals stren
stren = ...
```

Answer (score 0):

Not really sure if you are familiar with class vs instance methods, but try this:

```
class Player():
    name = "UnknownName"
    stren = 10
    dex = 10
    con = 10
    intel = 10
    wis = 10
    cha = 10

    @classmethod
    def randAssign(cls):
        stat_List = [cls.stren, 
                     cls.dex, 
                     cls.con, 
                     cls.intel, 
                     cls.wis, 
                     cls.cha]

        for stat in stat_List:
             r_1 = random.randint(1,6)
             r_2 = random.randint(1,6)
             r_3 = random.randint(1,6)
             r_4 = random.randint(1,6)

             stat_Val = r_1 + r_2 + r_3 + r_4 - min(r_1, r_2, r_3, r_4)
             stat = stat_Val
```

Given what it looks like you are doing (creating random Player stats), this would be more approriate if done per Player *instance* under the `__init__` call upon instantiation.

Read this [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17134653/difference-between-class-and-instance-methods) for more information on the difference between the two methods.

**Edit:** To illustrate point in comments...

This is the problem you will encounter with your method (my above example only resolves your scoping issue, not your implementation one)

```
class Temp:
    stat = 1
    @classmethod
    def test(cls):
        stats = [cls.stat] # container contains copies of primitive types 
        print (stats) # [1]
        for i in range(1):
            stats[i] = (stats[i] + 2) * 3 # 1 + 2 * 3 = 9
        print (stats) # [9]
        print (cls.stat) # 1
```

To do what comments appear you want to:

```
class Temp:
    stats = {'stat': 1}
    @classmethod
    def test(cls):
        stats = [cls.stats] # container contains reference to another container
        print (stats) # {'stat': 1}
        for stat in stats:
            cls.stats[stat] = (cls.stats[stat] + 2) * 3 # 1 + 2 * 3 = 9
        print (stats) # {'stat': 9}
        print (cls.stats) # {'stat': 9}, look they updated!
```

Comment: This method fails to modify the class variables in exactly the same way as the OPs attempts

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Their problem was scope, I've updated to give example as to what happens given their implementation, but those are two different issues to address for the OP.