# Class method not finding the argument given

Tags: python

I just learned how to create Binary Search Trees in C#. I decided to try to code the same thing in Python 3.x. However, when I got to my Print method, this error showed up:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\danie\Desktop\Python\BinarySearchTree\BinarySearchTree\BinarySearchTree.py", line 62, in <module>
    b.BSTprint()
  File "C:\Users\danie\Desktop\Python\BinarySearchTree\BinarySearchTree\BinarySearchTree.py", line 46, in BSTprint
    BST.Print(current)
TypeError: Print() missing 1 required positional argument: 'cur'
```

The problem, I did put in the required positional argument. I tried fixing it myself and found that if I remove the *self* parameter, it works. However, I always thought you needed to have that *self* parameter in all of the class methods. I have no idea what is wrong. Here is the code

```
import random
class BST:
    #Node class 
    class Node:
        data = None
        left = None
        right = None
        def __init__(self, d):
            self.data = d
    first = None
    #Add method
    def Add(self, d):
        #Checks if the Binary Search Tree is empty
       if(BST.first == None):
           BST.first = BST.Node(d)
           #Debugging purposes
           #print("Added: {}".format(d))
           return;
       else:
           newNode = BST.Node(d)
           cur = BST.first
           while(cur != None):
               if(cur.data < newNode.data):
                   if(cur.left == None):
                       cur.left = newNode
                       #print("Added: {}".format(newNode.data))
                       return
                   else:
                       cur = cur.left
               elif(cur.data > newNode.data):
                   if(cur.right == None):
                       cur.right = newNode
                       #print("Added: {}".format(newNode.data))
                       return
                   else:
                       cur = cur.right
               else:
                    print("Value already in BST")
                    return


    def BSTprint(self):
        current = BST.first
        if(current == None):
            return
        BST.Print(current)
    def Print(self, cur):

        if(cur.left != None):
            BST.Print(cur.left)
        print(cur.data)
        if(cur.right != None):
            BST.Print(cur.right)



b = BST()
#Adds values into BST
for i in range(10):
    x = random.randint(1,100)
    b.Add(x)
b.BSTprint()
```

Comment: `BST.Print(current)` should be `self.Print(current)`.

Comment: That's a lot of code! Please slim it down to a [mcve]

Comment: a class inside a class! neat!

Comment: @user3483203 Well, the core problem is in the printing methods, but the OP didn't know exactly what the cause of the problem is, and so IMHO it's reasonable that he included the node insertion code. At least this code is runnable (once the print methods are repaired), even if it isn't quite minimal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As others have noted, in the `Print` method you need to call `BSTprint` as an instance method, eg `self.BSTprint(node)` so that the instance gets passed to the method correctly. But there are a few other issues with your code.

Doing `first = None` creates `first` as a class attribute, which means it would be shared by all `BST` instances. That's not a good idea: each instance should have its own root node! Of course, if the program only creates a single `BST` instance you wouldn't notice that bug, but if you decide that you want to create several trees then Bad Things would happen. ;)

Instead, you should creates `first` as an instance attribute, the usual way to do that is in the `__init__` method.

Your code defines the `Node` class inside the BST class. It's fine to do that, but it's a little unusual in Python. It's simpler just to make it a separate class. Once again, you're defining the `Node` attributes as class attributes. That's actually ok here, since you never modify those class attributes: your `Add` method creates instance attributes with the same names that "shadow" the class attributes. However, it makes the code a little simpler to analyse if you get rid of those class attributes and simply use instance attributes from the outset.

Here's a modified version of your code. I made a few cosmetic changes so that the code conforms with the Python [PEP-0008](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) style guide. Simple variable, attribute, and method names should begin with lower case letters. I also got rid of redundant parentheses. And it's recommended to use `is` when testing for the `None` singleton, it's a little more efficient (and nicer to read) than using `==` or `!=` value testing.

I changed `first` to `root`, in line with Berk Özbalcı's remark. And I gave `Node` a `__repr__` method to make it easier to print the Node data.

I also added a call to `random.seed`, with a hard-coded seed value so that the program generates the same numbers each time we run it. That makes testing and debugging much easier. It can be hard to figure out what's going wrong when the data keeps changing.

```
import random

random.seed(42)

class Node:
    """ A binary tree node """
    def __init__(self, d):
        self.data = d
        self.left = self.right = None

    def __repr__(self):
        return repr(self.data)

class BST:
    """ Binary search tree """
    def __init__(self):
        self.root = None

    def add(self, d):
       # Check if the Binary Search Tree is empty
       if self.root is None:
           self.root = Node(d)
           #Debugging purposes
           print("Added: {} root".format(self.root))
           return
       else:
           newNode = Node(d)
           cur = self.root
           while cur is not None:
               if cur.data < newNode.data:
                   if cur.left is None:
                       cur.left = newNode
                       print("Added: {} left".format(newNode))
                       return
                   else:
                       cur = cur.left
               elif cur.data > newNode.data:
                   if cur.right is None:
                       cur.right = newNode
                       print("Added: {} right".format(newNode))
                       return
                   else:
                       cur = cur.right
               else:
                    print("Value already in BST:", d)
                    return

    def bst_print(self):
        current = self.root
        if current is None:
            return
        self.show(current)

    def show(self, cur=None):
        if cur.left is not None:
            self.show(cur.left)
        print(cur)
        if cur.right is not None:
            self.show(cur.right)


b = BST()

# Add values into BST
for i in range(10):
    x = random.randint(1, 100)
    print(x)
    b.add(x)

print('\nSorted')
b.bst_print()
```

**output**

```
82
Added: 82 root
15
Added: 15 right
4
Added: 4 right
95
Added: 95 left
36
Added: 36 left
32
Added: 32 right
29
Added: 29 right
18
Added: 18 right
95
Value already in BST: 95
14
Added: 14 left

Sorted
95
82
36
32
29
18
15
14
4
```

Answer (score 1):

You've got class variables and instance variables mixed up.

In Python, the first argument of methods are reserved for the calling object (except in some cases they aren't, such as in classmethods or staticmethods). Modify the Add method like this:

```
class BST:
...
    def Add(self, d):
        if self.first is None:
            self.first = BST.Node(d)
            return
    ...
```

Note that `BST.Node(d)` is still the same, because I'm referring to something that is belonging to the class: another class.

Modify `BST.Print(current)` to `self.Print(current)`.

It's uncommon to refer to the root node of a BST as `first`, prefer `root` instead!

Answer (score 1):

Things I would like to highlight:

`BST` is a class

`Print` is a object method(bound to object and not class) and it requires the object reference to be passed(`self`) which is different from other languages Java/C++.

You're calling `BST.Print` which is similar to calling static methods in Java/C++, but its wrong because `Print` method takes object parameter

Since you're calling a method that is object bound(since it takes `self` parameter), you need to call it with objects.

The point is:

If you're using methods with self parameter then they should be called with objects. If you want to call them from class then you can use `@staticmethod` and remove the self parameter and pass the object you want to process

Please refer:
[Difference between Class and Instance methods](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17134653/difference-between-class-and-instance-methods)

Hope this helps