# AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'env'

Tags: odoo-13

I am trying to select some data from the database.

I tried to call a function like this :

```
class Test(models.Model): 
    _name = 'test.test'
    _description = 'test.test'

    emri = fields.Char()
    mbiemri = fields.Char()
    qyteti = fields.Char()

    def getdata(self): 
        data = self.env['test3'].search([])
        print(data)
```

I am getting this error : AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'env'

Comment: How did you call `getdata`?

Comment: I am trying to call it in python console in PyCharm IDE.

Comment: Launch odoo as a python [console environment](https://www.odoo.com/documentation/13.0/reference/cmdline.html#shell)

Comment: Yes in this way i have created my module , but when i write the function 'self' does not have the 'env' property neither the 'cr' property.

Comment: After starting the shell, use the following syntax to call `getdata` method: `self.env['test.test'].getdata()`

Comment: It does not solve my problem , but thank you for your response anyway.

Comment: What is the problem exactly?

Comment: I am trying to get some data from database and then to display those data in odoo view and I was trying with the method above. I want to call the function in order to see what data actually i was selecting. But when I call the function I am getting this error: AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'env'. I don't know if I was clear.

Comment: The missing part is how you started odoo and how you called that method

Comment: I have configured PyCharm for odoo development and there I called the method.

Comment: Describe how you configure and how you make the call

Comment: I have follow this tutorial for configuration :https://youtu.be/E21VfQqX55c. And in PyCharm console I make the call in this way : Test.getdata(Test.getdata)

Comment: You called the `gedata` method as a class method and you passed `Test.getdata` reference (function reference) this is why you got `AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'env'` .

Comment: But shouldn't the method be inside of a class ? Or if you can tell me in short terms how can I display some data from database. Sorry for disturbing so much :)

Comment: No problem, `getdata` is an [instance method and you call it like a class method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17134653/difference-between-class-and-instance-methods). you can use Odoo shell to interact with [ORM](https://www.odoo.com/documentation/13.0/reference/orm.html#reference-orm) and its functionalities (you must add shell argument when starting Odoo). You can also add a button to run that method or use `pgadmin` to use SQL queries. If you need to add some functionalities to Odoo I will be pleased to help you.