# How do I solve the NameError of a method of class in Python?

Tags: python, django

I was working on a small program and I am getting this `NameError`. Error is below:

`NameError: name 'create_user' is not defined`

Following is a short program that I wrote:

```
class UserManager():
    email = "abc"
    def create_user(email, password=None):
        user = (email, password)

    def create_superuser(email, password):
        user = create_user(
            email,
            password = password
            )
        return ("User is an admin")

password = input("Password: ")

User = UserManager()

print(User.create_superuser(password))
```

Comment: What exactly does this have to do with django?

Comment: Instance methods on a class have to take a mandatory argument `self` (or any other name), representing the instance calling the method.

Comment: Probably related/ a duplicate of [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17134653/difference-between-class-and-instance-methods](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17134653/difference-between-class-and-instance-methods)

Comment: Please study a turorial about classes, f.e. [https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html)

Comment: If you want the method to be a static method, put @ staticmethod. If you want it to be a class method  put @ classmethod on top of it and add parameter cls. Otherwise, add self parameter.

Comment: @schwobaseggl I am creating a custom user model in Django.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have amended your code and this would work, although it is not clear what you want to do.
As per previous comments here, you need to use self, and **init**.
The code below works but it still has no sense. It's just to make you see why you get an error.
Add return to each function and make it clear what each function should do.
(Also, it's a bit strange asking the password without the email).

```
class UserManager:
    def __init__(self):
        self.email = "abc"

    def create_user(self, email, password=None):
        user = (email, password)
        return user

    def create_superuser(self, email, password):
        self.create_user(email, password = password)
        return "User is an admin"

password = input("Password: ")
User = UserManager()
print(User.create_superuser(None, password))
```

Comment: Yeah, I know the code does not do anything useful, I actually instead of posting whole User Custom Model that I created in Django, just posted a part of it (also edited, to make it look a small normal program) that just prints `User is an admin`.