# Can't call/ access internal class method Python

Tags: python

Have a class with some methods, in one if this method I call another method which returns an error.

Code sample:

```
class Car:

    def __init__(self,Km,Brand):
        self.car_name=Brand
        self.car_kms=Km

    @classmethod
    def get_kms_updated(self):
        new_kms=__get_kms_cheating(self.car_kms,10)
        self.car_kms=new_kms
    
    @classmethod
    def __get_kms_cheating(self,int_km):
        return self.kms+int_km
```

Error message

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------

NameError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-29-1cdd478d0a60> in <module>
----> 1 first_car.get_kms_updated()

<ipython-input-27-904633893463> in get_kms_updated(self)
      7     @classmethod
      8     def get_kms_updated(self):
----> 9         new_kms=__get_kms_cheating(self.km,10)
     10         self.car_kms=new_kms
     11 

NameError: name '_Car__get_kms_cheating' is not defined
```

Comment: Please fix your indentation.  It's not clear what functions (if any) are supposed to be members of the `Car` class.

Comment: btw It is traditional when you have a `@classmethod` for the method to be like: `def get_kms_updated(cls):`

Comment: The entire point of class methods is that they don't need access to `self`.  But those functions are definitely using `self`, so why do you want them to be class methods?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, there are several errors in your program.

1. You should define class members, if you want to use in class methods. Like `Car.car_kms = Km`, otherwise you will receive an error - `type object 'Car' has no attribute 'car_kms'`
2. You should call the class method like this - `Car.__get_kms_cheating()`
3. We recommend that the parameters of the class method be written as `cls` instead of `self` which is for instance method.

I think this is what you want

```py
class Car:
    def __init__(self, Km, Brand):
        self.car_name = Brand
        Car.car_kms = Km
        
    @classmethod
    def get_kms_updated(cls):
        new_kms = Car.__get_kms_cheating(10)
        Car.car_kms = new_kms
        
    @classmethod
    def __get_kms_cheating(cls, int_km):
        return cls.car_kms + int_km
```

Comment: Thank you very much, I need to learn a lot and your explanation really helped

Comment: @AlejandroA No problem, looking at this answer here.https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17134653/difference-between-class-and-instance-methods may also help you. Btw, I don't know what the usage scenario of this program is, I personally feel that there is no need to use class methods here.