# tkinter run function of another class with button

Tags: python, tkinter

This is my code:

```
class TimeFrame(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)

        self.text = tk.Text(self, height=10, width=110)
        self.vsb = tk.Scrollbar(self, orient="vertical", command=self.text.yview)
        self.text.configure(yscrollcommand=self.vsb.set)
        self.vsb.pack(side="right", fill="y")
        self.text.pack(side="left", fill="both", expand=True)

    def add_timestamp(self):
        self.text.insert("end", time.ctime() + "\n")
        self.text.see("end")
        self.after(1000, self.add_timestamp)


class ButtonFrame(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)

        self.button = tk.Button(self, text="Start Time", command=self.start_time)
        self.button.pack()

    def start_time(self):
        TimeFrame.add_timestamp()
        


if __name__ == "__main__":
    root = tk.Tk()
    time_frame = TimeFrame(root)
    time_frame.pack(fill="both", expand=True, padx=10, pady=20)
    button_frame = ButtonFrame(root)
    button_frame.pack(fill="both", expand=True, pady=(0, 20))
    root.mainloop()
```

I want that the `add_timestamp()` function runs when the button is clicked.

Without an argument in `TimeFrame.add_timestamp()` I get an error saying missing argument "self".
What do I need to write as an argument there that it is working properly?

Answer (score 2):

Note that `TimeFrame.add_timestamp(self)` is actually an instance method. That means, that you cannot call it without providing a specific instance, which is then passed as `self`.

Imagine you would create two TimeFrames `a = TimeFrame(root)` and `b = TimeFrame(root)`, then you would need to call `add_timestamp` for one of them using either `a.add_timestamp()` or `b.add_timestamp()`.

So in your case, you already have a `TimeFrame` instance (called `time_frame`). Now what you need, is a reference from `ButtonFrame` to `TimeFrame`, so that each `ButtonFrame` can refer to a specific `TimeFrame` *instance*.

As a simple solution, you could pass `time_frame` to `button_frame` on creation and store it as an attribute. You can then call `add_timestamp` on that specific instance (not tested):

```python
class TimeFrame(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)

        self.text = tk.Text(self, height=10, width=110)
        self.vsb = tk.Scrollbar(self, orient="vertical", command=self.text.yview)
        self.text.configure(yscrollcommand=self.vsb.set)
        self.vsb.pack(side="right", fill="y")
        self.text.pack(side="left", fill="both", expand=True)

    def add_timestamp(self):
        self.text.insert("end", time.ctime() + "\n")
        self.text.see("end")
        self.after(1000, self.add_timestamp)


class ButtonFrame(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, root, time_frame, *args, **kwargs):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, root, *args, **kwargs)

        self.time_frame = time_frame
        self.button = tk.Button(self, text="Start Time", command=self.start_time)
        self.button.pack()

    def start_time(self):
        self.time_frame.add_timestamp()
        


if __name__ == "__main__":
    root = tk.Tk()
    time_frame = TimeFrame(root)
    time_frame.pack(fill="both", expand=True, padx=10, pady=20)
    button_frame = ButtonFrame(root, time_frame)
    button_frame.pack(fill="both", expand=True, pady=(0, 20))
    root.mainloop()
```

Take a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17134709/12661819) for a better explanation on the difference between class and instance methods.

Comment: When I run this code I get AttributeError: '_tkinter.tkapp' object has no attribute 'add_timestamp'. I don't understand the linked answer either :/.

Comment: Ah, I see. Try again, if it still does not work I‘ll have a look once I‘m back at a computer.