# Short way to get all field names of a pydantic class

Tags: python, oop, pydantic

Minimal example of the class:

```
from pydantic import BaseModel

class AdaptedModel(BaseModel):
    def get_all_fields(self, alias=False):
        return list(self.schema(by_alias=alias).get("properties").keys())

class TestClass(AdaptedModel):
    test: str
```

The way it works:

```
dm.TestClass.get_all_fields(dm.TestClass)
```

Is there a way to make it work without giving the class again?

Desired way to get all field names:

```
dm.TestClass.get_all_fields()
```

It would also work if the field names are assigned to an attribute. Just any way to make it make it more readable

Comment: I have tried using `__post_init__` or `__init__` - but pydantic seems to have a mind of its own

Answer (score 53, accepted):

What about just using `__fields__`:

```
from pydantic import BaseModel

class AdaptedModel(BaseModel):
    parent_attr: str

class TestClass(AdaptedModel):
    child_attr: str
        
TestClass.__fields__
```

Output:

```
{'parent_attr': ModelField(name='parent_attr', type=str, required=True),
 'child_attr': ModelField(name='child_attr', type=str, required=True)}
```

This is just a dict and you could get only the field names simply by: `TestClass.__fields__.keys()`

See model properties: https://pydantic-docs.helpmanual.io/usage/models/#model-properties

Comment: And we can get using  list(TestClass.__fields__.keys()) , a flat list of field names

Comment: This certainly works, but I don't feel that using a restricted attribute like `__fields__` is the pythonic way of doing this. If it is restricted, it is for a reason. I'd go for the classmethod solution suggested by @5th

Comment: @dalonsoa, I wouldn't say magic attributes (such as ``__fields__``) are necessarily meant to be restricted in terms of reading (magic attributes are a bit different than private attributes). It just means they have some special purpose and they probably shouldn't be overridden accidentally. The docs describe this attribute and do not say you shouldn't use it so I don't think this is meant to be a restricted attribute in terms of reading.

Comment: Sure, point taken - I'm not against it. But I still thing it is a bit misleading to use magic attributes as a public interface for a python class. As, in general and in most cases, they are meant to be for internal use only.

Comment: The `__fields__` attribute is deprecated, use `model_fields` instead.

Answer (score 13):

Update January 2024: This answer was my method to get the fields before pydantic v1. In v1 the `__fields__` was added. This was then depreced with the introduction of `model_fields` in v2.

---

Okay the solution is to use a [class-method instead of an instance method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17134653/difference-between-class-and-instance-methods):

```
from pydantic import BaseModel, Field

class AdaptedModel(BaseModel):
    @classmethod
    def get_field_names(cls,alias=False):
        return list(cls.schema(alias).get("properties").keys())

class TestClass(AdaptedModel):
    test: str = Field(alias="TEST")
```

We are using Python 3.6.8 and apparently it was already introduce. For completeness sake can somebody comment since when `@classmethod` exists? I assume since 3.6.

Comment: classmethod has been around for a long time https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/functions.html#classmethod

New in version 2.2.
Changed in version 2.4: Function decorator syntax added.

Answer (score 4):

You can do simply

```
TestClass.model_fields
```

Comment: Just for context: I asked this Question with Pydantic before it even reached v1. Getting a list of model fields was a pain. The `model_fields` is a new property since v2

Answer (score 2):

Here's a solution that combines the answers from `miksus` and `5th` to support listing field names by their alias:

```
from pydantic import BaseModel
from pydantic.fields import ModelField, Field

class AdaptedModel(BaseModel):
    base_field_1: str = Field(alias="base_field_1_alias")

    @classmethod
    def get_field_names(cls, by_alias=False) -> list[str]:
        field_names = []
        for k, v in cls.__fields__.items():
            if by_alias and isinstance(v, ModelField):
                field_names.append(v.alias)
            else:
                field_names.append(k)

        return field_names

class TestClass(AdaptedModel):
    test_field_1: str = Field(alias="test_field_1_alias")
    test_field_2: str
```

To be used in the following manner:

```
print(TestClass.get_field_names(by_alias=True))
```

which outputs

```
['base_field_1_alias', 'test_field_1_alias', 'test_field_2']
```

Or you can get a list of non-aliased names with `by_alias=False` (the default):

```
print(TestClass.get_field_names(by_alias=False))
```

which outputs:

```
['base_field_1', 'test_field_1', 'test_field_2']
```

Comment: As of 21/03/2024, `ModelField` seems to be throwing an error when using Pydantic version 2.x, here's an open discussion: https://github.com/pydantic/pydantic/discussions/7185

Answer (score 1):

If you need also the type of each field you might just use `jsonref`:

```
import jsonref
from pprint import pprint
from enum import Enum

class Values(Enum):
    a = 'a'
    b = 'b'


class Mdl(BaseModel):
    par: Values = Field(
        title="par",
        description="description of my parameter"
    )
    par2: str = Field(
        title="par2",
        description="description of my parameter"
    )
    par3: int = Field(
        title="par3",
        description="description of my parameter"
    )

    class Config:
        """ Automatically convert enum to values """
        use_enum_values = True


pprint(jsonref.loads(Mdl.schema_json()))
```

produces

```
{'definitions': {'Values': {'description': 'An enumeration.',
                            'enum': ['a', 'b'],
                            'title': 'Values'}},
 'properties': {'par': {'allOf': [{'title': 'Values', 'description': 'An enumeration.', 'enum': ['a', 'b']}],
                        'description': 'description of my parameter',
                        'title': 'MyParameter'},
                'par2': {'description': 'description of my parameter',
                         'title': 'MyParameter',
                         'type': 'string'},
                'par3': {'description': 'description of my parameter',
                         'title': 'MyParameter',
                         'type': 'integer'}},
 'required': ['par', 'par2', 'par3'],
 'title': 'Mdl',
 'type': 'object'}
```

Latter might further cleaned with

```
sch = jsonref.loads(Mdl.schema_json())
    for par in sch['properties']:
        if 'allOf' in sch['properties']['par']:
            if 'enum' in sch['properties']['par']['allOf'][0]:
                sch['properties']['par']['title'] = sch['properties']['par']['allOf'][0]['title']
                sch['properties']['par']['allowed_values'] = sch['properties']['par']['allOf'][0]['enum']
                sch['properties']['par'].pop('allOf')
```

that returns

```
{'definitions': {'Values': {'description': 'An enumeration.',
                            'enum': ['a', 'b'],
                            'title': 'Values'}},
 'properties': {'par': {'allowed_values': ['a', 'b'],
                        'description': 'description of my parameter',
                        'title': 'Values'},
                'par2': {'description': 'description of my parameter',
                         'title': 'MyParameter',
                         'type': 'string'},
                'par3': {'description': 'description of my parameter',
                         'minimum': 0,
                         'title': 'MyParameter',
                         'type': 'integer'}},
 'required': ['par', 'par2', 'par3'],
 'title': 'Mdl',
 'type': 'object'}
```