# Why is the instance variable not getting changed?

Tags: python, class-method

```
class Player:
    def __init__(self, Name, Age, Sex):
        self.Name = Name
        self.Age = Age
        self.Sex = Sex
        
        self.validate(Name,Age,Sex)
        

    @classmethod
    def validate(cls, Name, Age, Sex):
        if (not isinstance(Age,int)) or Age < 0:
            Age = int(input('Please input a valid integer greter than 0'))
            return cls(Name,Age,Sex)
            
        
    def showDetails(self):
        return f'Player name: {self.Name}. Player age: {self.Age}'


a = Player('Nail',-25,'F')
a.showDetails()
```

Output:

```
Please input a valid integer greter than 0 20
'Player name: Nail. Player age: -25'
```

The variable `Age` is not changing. It remains on its initial state.

Comment: Because your `validate` method is a class method, and returns a new instance of Player... that you never use. Instead of a class method, use a regular instance method and modify the instance variables Name, Age, Sex directly.

Comment: What is the motivation in making `validate` a class method? It is an instance of the class that needs validation.

Comment: Having variable names with leading capital letters implies these are classes, which they are not.

Comment: Doing input inside a validation function is also highly irregular. You should return the result of the validation test, `True` or `False`, or perhaps `raise`. You should leave the input part to the caller. The way you're calling this could also lead to going deeper and deeper in the stack, indefinitely.

Comment: `validate()` is a class method, meaning it does _not_ have access to the instance attributes.  Why on earth did you make this a class method?

Comment: Tip: If you have constraints on the inputs, define an error class you can `raise` and use that instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You almost got it. As some comments point, `validate` can't have access to the specific member of an instance of the object because it is a class method. You can do instead

```
def __init__(self, Name, Age, Sex):
    self.Name = Name
    self.Age = self.validate(Age)
    self.Sex = Sex                                                                                  
                                                                                                        
def validate(self, Age):
    while (not isinstance(Age, int)) or Age < 0:
        Age = int(input('Please input a valid integer greter than 0: '))
    return Age
```

That said, if the validation is as simple as checking inequalities, you could just stick the operation inside of the constructor without the need for an auxiliary function. Something like this:

```
def __init__(self, Name, Age, Sex):
    while (not isinstance(Age, int)) or Age < 0):
        Age = int(input('Please input a valid integer greter than 0: '))

    self.Name = Name
    self.Age = Age
    self.Sex = Sex
```

Comment: The extra validation function can be useful if it was a standalone/separate function, especially since it has an input prompt. It should be called _before_ instantiating an object. As other comments also pointed out, having an input prompt as part of init is highly irregular.

Answer (score 0):

The main problem with your code is that you are incorrectly using a class method, which doesn't have access to the instance variables that needs to be validated and replaced. Review the related post on the [Difference between class and instance methods](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17134709/2745495) to understand what a class method is and what it's for.

Furthermore, your code

```
return cls(Name,Age,Sex)
```

instantiates a new, *different* object, different from the original one that was just instantiated with the invalid `Age`, and, as [tadman pointed out in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74978068/why-the-instance-value-of-variable-is-not-changing-in-python#comment132314165_74978068), can lead to a continuous chain of instantiation, validation, instantiation, ... etc. which doesn't even modify the original instance. This is *definitely* not what you want.

The simple, yet a bit naive solution, would be to replace your class method with an instance method and then use a regular `while` loop to keep prompting for input until you get a valid `Age`, similar to what's demonstrated in [JustLearning's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/users/19962393/justlearning):

```
In [4]: class Player:
   ...:     def __init__(self, Name, Age, Sex):
   ...:         self.Name = Name
   ...:         self.Age = Age
   ...:         self.Sex = Sex
   ...: 
   ...:         self.validate()
   ...: 
   ...:     def validate(self):
   ...:         while (not isinstance(self.Age, int)) or self.Age < 0:
   ...:             self.Age = int(input('Please input a valid integer greter than 0'))
```

But, while that certainly works, it's highly unusual and a bit of code smell to have an input prompt as part of instantiating a class. The better practice would be prompting for `Age` and getting all the other variables *before* instantiating the class, as part of a *separate* function. Your class should just act like a container for a `Player`'s details and functions, and this would also make it much easier to write unit tests for the `Player` class.

Furthermore, doing `int(input(...)` can possibly raise a `ValueError` Exception if the input isn't a valid integer. Checking with `isinstance` would not properly handle non-integer inputs. See [Asking the user for input until they give a valid response](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23294658/2745495) for better ways to validate.

My alternative solution would be:

```
In [22]: class Player:
    ...:     def __init__(self, Name, Age, Sex):
    ...:         self.Name = Name
    ...:         self.Age = Age
    ...:         self.Sex = Sex
    ...: 
    ...:     def showDetails(self):
    ...:         return f'Player name: {self.Name}. Player age: {self.Age}'
    ...: 

In [23]: def get_age():
    ...:     while True:
    ...:         try:
    ...:             Age = int(input('Please input a valid integer greater than 0 '))
    ...:         except ValueError:
    ...:             continue
    ...:         if Age < 0:
    ...:             continue
    ...:         else:
    ...:             break
    ...:     return Age
    ...: 

In [24]: Age = get_age()
Please input a valid integer greater than 0 -5
Please input a valid integer greater than 0 -16
Please input a valid integer greater than 0 notinteger
Please input a valid integer greater than 0 22

In [25]: a = Player('Nail',Age,'F')

In [26]: a.showDetails()
Out[26]: 'Player name: Nail. Player age: 22'
```

If somehow you *really still* want your class to do some validation, it should just raise some form of an Exception if it gets invalid input, and then let your outer code handle it.

```
In [32]: class Player:
    ...:     def __init__(self, Name, Age, Sex):
    ...:         self.Name = Name
    ...:         self.Age = Age
    ...:         self.Sex = Sex
    ...:         self.validate()
    ...: 
    ...:     def validate(self):
    ...:         if (not isinstance(self.Age, int)) or self.Age < 0:
    ...:             raise ValueError("Age should be int and >0")

In [36]: try:
    ...:     Age = get_age()
    ...:     a = Player('Nail', Age, 'F')
    ...: except ValueError:
    ...:     print("Cannot instantiate Player, invalid details")
```

Finally, since this answer is all about best practices, you should follow [PEP8 Style Guide for Naming Conventions](https://peps.python.org/pep-0008/#naming-conventions) and use **all-lowercase** for function parameters and instance variable names:

```
class Player:
    def __init__(self, name, age, sex):
        self.name = name
        self.age = age
        self.sex = sex
```

Only use uppercase/CapWords style `Age` only if `Age` is a class.